# Writing a MATCH or LOOKUP statement with a precondition

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, match, worksheet-function

I am looking to write a statement with the following conditions:

```
If A1="apples" then match B1 in Sheet4 column C  
If a match is found return the value in F1  
If no match then return the value of F2.
```

The formula will be written in D1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want may be something like:

```
=IF(A1<>"apples","oops!",IF(ISERROR(MATCH(B1,Sheet4!C:C,0)),F2,F1))
```

assuming only the ColumnC enty is on Sheet4, all others on the same sheet as the formula, and that if A1 does not equal "apples" you want to be warned (in the example with  `oops!`) though you may prefer to change that to `""`.